# Value of type AnyObject has no member Generator

Tags: swift

I am learning and I could not figure it out so far by myself.

My code is:

```
 func takeScreenshot(completionHandler handler: ((NSData!) -> Void)!)
    {
        // find out video connection
        var videoConnection: AVCaptureConnection?
        for conn in stillImageOutput!.connections {
            for port in conn.inputPorts {
                if port.mediaType == AVMediaTypeVideo {
                    videoConnection = conn as? AVCaptureConnection
                    break
                }
            }
            if videoConnection != nil {
                break
            }
        }
        stillImageOutput!.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(videoConnection) { (sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, err: NSError!) in
            let data = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
            handler(data)
        }
    }
```

In loop "for port in conn.inputPorts" I get the error.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: type `AnyObject` has no member what?? Usually there is some thing to end that statement to clarify what you're trying to manipulate that doesn't exist

Comment: Maybe you mean to do `connections.inputPorts`?... no idea, not enough info.

Comment: Value of type AnyObject has no member in 'Generator'

Answer (score 0):

You actually have the same issue in two places. First is wit the `connections` property which appears to be a property of the `AVCaptureOutput` class. `connections` is declared as an `NSArray`.

The second, similar issue is with your use of `inputPorts`. `inputPorts` appears to be a property of the `AVCaptureConnection` class. `inputPorts` is declared as an `NSArray`.

The problem you are having is that `conn` and `port` end up with a type of `AnyObject` because Swift has no idea what type of objects are in the two arrays.

So your attempt to access a property on a variable of type `AnyObject` results in the error.

You have two options.

1. Cast the `connections` array to a Swift array of `AVCaptureSession` and `inputPorts` to a Swift array of `AVCaptureInputPort`.
2. Cast `conn` to `AVCaptureSession` and `port` to `AVCaptureInputPort`.

Comment: Glad to help. Please don't forget to accept answers that solve your questions. This lets people know your question has been solved.